# Can I check if the screen is dimmed by the Clock app?

Tags: screen, android

The Clock app has a button that dims the screen. I'd like to check from a Service whether or not the screen has been dimmed by this method. But I cannot find any way to get this information. The following expression, for example, is not affected by this status:

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)
```

Nor `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE`. I also tried `PowerManager.isScreenOn()` and `UiModeManager.getNightMode()`, but neither of them gives me the info I need.

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dim the screen without changing the system brightness using `getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness`. So `Settings.System.getInt()` isn't going to help you check.

They may also be using a dark overlay with an alpha value to dim the screen.

Either way, I'm fairly sure there's no way to query the brightness unless you have access to the `Window` that's being adjusted.

Comment: I was afraid of this. If the clock app doesn't broadcast an intent about it, I'd probably need low-level access to the hardware to check this condition. I assume that's also the case for status bar visibility? That was another avenue I've been exploring.